Customize table number in quarto
I'm writing a journal article and I'm putting each table in its own Quarto file, because I don't like to put them into the main tex and moreover I think there's a bug in apaquarto extension that prevents labelled tables from spanning multiple pages.
So a table quarto file looks like this:
---
format:
  pdf:
    papersize: A4
    classoption: [landscape]
---

|a  |b  |
|---|---|
|d1 |d2 |

: A simple table

The problem is that the caption is always named "Table 1".
How can I customize table numbers in quarto?

I don't get a caption nor number if I try your example

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz so so sorry. I have updated the example.

You should really test the example before posting a question

I forgot the last line. Sorry again.

You can choose the number by changing the table counter:
---
format:
  pdf:
    papersize: A4
    classoption: [landscape]
---

\addtocounter{table}{41}

|a  |b  |
|---|---|
|d1 |d2 |

: A simple table



oh I had no idea you could put LaTeX code directly in Quarto. Thanks!

I mean, isn't this supposed to be raw content?

raw content is only necessary if quarto messes the commands up during parsing. Otherwise you can simply use latex.

oh ok. Thanks! (2 more characters to go).

Just wanted to share the function I ended up with that writes a dataframe as a Quarto table:
#' Write a table in Quarto format
#'
#' @param df A dataframe
#' @param fp The file to write the table into
#' @param tablenum The progressive number of the table in the paper
#' @param caption Table caption
#' @param landscape Whether the paper should be placed in landscape mode
#'
#' @return None
#'
#' @export
write_quarto_table <- function(df, 
                               fp, 
                               tablenum = 1, 
                               caption = "This is the caption", 
                               landscape = TRUE) {
  header <- paste0("---
format:
  pdf:
    papersize: A4
    classoption: [", ifelse(landscape, "landscape", ""), "]
  docx: default
  odt: default
---

\\addtocounter{table}{", paste0(tablenum - 1), "}

")
  tablemd <- knitr::kable(df, format = "markdown")
  tablemd <- paste0(tablemd, collapse = "\n")
  caption <- paste0(": ", caption)
  txt <- c(header, tablemd, "\n\n", caption)
  cat(txt, file = outfp, sep = "")
}

